# ScrollBarCover problems with Opera browser

Tags: javascript, mootools, scrollbar, opera

I have a plugin made for Mootools framework and for some reason that is beyond me it does not work. I have leteraly tried everything I could imagine. But for some reason I can't check off the bug.

Here is the link to the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jnbdz/CQcF8/4/

Link to the project: http://mootools.net/forge/p/scrollbarcover

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: mod your fiddle to have the class code inline so ppl can edit it if they are ever to try fixing. i downloaded opera and it works -ish - bit fast on the scroll and does not detatch but works.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/RcXcN/ It's when you drag the knob (the black cube) that everything goes crazy. It works fin in Firefox and Webkit browsers.

Comment: its not too bad, opera 11.10 here - aside from 2 issues: when dragging it down, it scrolls too fast - disproportionately so to the actual control and mouse movement. and 2, you can mouseup and move away w/o it discovering it so it would continue to scroll. the problem here is partially to do with the Fx.Slider.js plugin - however, not the code you've written. And in most part, its to do with David Walsh's scrollSpy - seems to work much nicer and far more accurately w/o it: http://jsfiddle.net/RcXcN/1/ Basing your class on 2 others is a bit... ambitious! good luck - who cares about opera anyway

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff your proposing that I look into Fx.Slider.js? But I am not sure what I am suppose to look for... I agree, who cares about Opera... But it does not look good to clients... And I am planning to use this script for my website... Thanks man for your time and help!

Comment: no, it looks like the scrollSpy plugin that causes it, mostly - http://jsfiddle.net/RcXcN/5/ is just lovely w/o scrollSpy, only downside is - i changed overflow: hidden and now this loses `mousewheeel` support but the scrollbar functions just fine. otherwise, how do you deal with accessibility and people that set a thick scrollbar and make it cross-OS compliant?

Comment: Thanks, I will try to add your little hack to my class. Do you want me to add your name to the credits? Thanks again :)

Comment: no - i am good. got my own [plugins](http://mootools.net/forge/profile/D_mitar) to worry about :)